# Animate captions and slides separately in Bootstrap 5 carousel?

Tags: javascript, css, http, carousel, bootstrap-5

Novice coder, doing this as a (self-imposed) excercise.

I have a bootstrap 5 carousel with three slides with two lines of captions each. Each time a slide leaves the window, the top caption moves up, and the bottom caption moves down. Then with the next slide, the new captions move into place in the reverse direction.

I've *almost* got it, but I'm stuck on one last problem: since the caption `div` is within the slide `div`, the captions inherit the sliding animation, making them move diagonally when the slides change. In addition, the slides don't stick together. There's a bit of white space between them when they change. The interference apparently goes both ways.

I've tried just taking the caption `div` out of the slide `div` and putting it after it, but then all captions that appear after the active slides overlap.

Is there a good way to separate the two divs so they don't interfere with each other?

Here's a codepen where you can see the problem: https://codepen.io/AlexanderSplat/pen/YzZvEaM

And here's the same one, but with the caption `div`s taken out of the slide `div`s, so you can see what it should look like (except for the overlapping text): https://codepen.io/AlexanderSplat/pen/vYxROqo

The same in code snippets (which aren't working for me right now, but I assume that's just due to the Fastly disruption from a few minutes ago):

Bad transitions:

```js
const topcap = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel-caption");
const bottomcap = document.querySelectorAll(".caption-bottom");
const slideclass = ("slide");

var TACarousel = document.querySelector("#CarouselTextAnim");

TACarousel.addEventListener("slide.bs.carousel", function() {
  topcap.forEach(cap => cap.classList.add(slideclass));
  bottomcap.forEach(cap => cap.classList.add(slideclass));
});

TACarousel.addEventListener("slid.bs.carousel", function() {
  topcap.forEach(cap => cap.classList.remove(slideclass));
  bottomcap.forEach(cap => cap.classList.remove(slideclass));
});
```

```css
.carousel-inner .carousel-item {
  transition: transform 2s ease;
}

.h1-carousel {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(2, 15, 19, 0.70);
  font-family: 'Julius Sans One';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 4vw;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s;
}

.carousel-caption.slide {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.caption-bottom {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 4vh;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s;
}

.caption-bottom.slide {
  bottom: -90vh;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Top Motion Productions</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.2/css/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.2/css/v4-shims.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,300italic,400,700|Julius+Sans+One|Roboto+Condensed:300,400" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 0" id="carousel">
    <section class="slideshow">
      <div id="CarouselTextAnim" class="carousel slide carousel-slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="2000" data-bs-pause="false">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="https://cutewallpaper.org/21/black-1920x1080-wallpaper/Dark-Desktop-Backgrounds-1920x1080-,-Best-Background-Images-.jpg" class="img-carousel d-block w-100" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1 id="carousel1" class="h1-carousel mb-5 caption-top">TOP CAPTION</h1>
              <h1 class="h1-carousel mb-5 caption-bottom">BOTTOM CAPTION</h1>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/THsknvO.jpg" class="img-carousel d-block w-100" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1 class="h1-carousel edit1 mb-5 caption-top">UP TOP</h1>
              <h1 class="h1-carousel mb-5 caption-bottom">DOWN LOW</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/z7tXPkz.jpg" class="img-carousel d-block w-100" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1 class="h1-carousel edit1 mb-5 caption-top">OVER</h1>
              <h1 class="h1-carousel mb-5 caption-bottom">UNDER</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#CarouselTextAnim" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#CarouselTextAnim" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.6.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-KsvD1yqQ1/1+IA7gi3P0tyJcT3vR+NdBTt13hSJ2lnve8agRGXTTyNaBYmCR/Nwi" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-nsg8ua9HAw1y0W1btsyWgBklPnCUAFLuTMS2G72MMONqmOymq585AcH49TLBQObG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.js"></script>
</body>
```

Good transitions, but overlapping letters:

```js
const topcap = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel-caption");
const bottomcap = document.querySelectorAll(".caption-bottom");
const slideclass = ("slide");

var TACarousel = document.querySelector("#CarouselTextAnim");

TACarousel.addEventListener("slide.bs.carousel", function() {
  topcap.forEach(cap => cap.classList.add(slideclass));
  bottomcap.forEach(cap => cap.classList.add(slideclass));
});

TACarousel.addEventListener("slid.bs.carousel", function() {
  topcap.forEach(cap => cap.classList.remove(slideclass));
  bottomcap.forEach(cap => cap.classList.remove(slideclass));
});
```

```css
.carousel-inner .carousel-item {
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}

.h1-carousel {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(2, 15, 19, 0.70);
  font-family: 'Julius Sans One';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 4vw;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.carousel-caption.slide {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.caption-bottom {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 4vh;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.caption-bottom.slide {
  bottom: -90vh;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Top Motion Productions</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.2/css/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.2/css/v4-shims.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,300italic,400,700|Julius+Sans+One|Roboto+Condensed:300,400" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 0" id="carousel">
    <section class="slideshow">
      <div id="CarouselTextAnim" class="carousel slide carousel-slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="2000" data-bs-pause="false">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="https://cutewallpaper.org/21/black-1920x1080-wallpaper/Dark-Desktop-Backgrounds-1920x1080-,-Best-Background-Images-.jpg" class="img-carousel d-block w-100" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1 id="carousel1" class="h1-carousel mb-5 caption-top">TOP CAPTION</h1>
            <h1 class="h1-carousel mb-5 caption-bottom">BOTTOM CAPTION</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/THsknvO.jpg" class="img-carousel d-block w-100" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1 class="h1-carousel edit1 mb-5 caption-top">UP TOP</h1>
            <h1 class="h1-carousel mb-5 caption-bottom">DOWN LOW</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/z7tXPkz.jpg" class="img-carousel d-block w-100" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1 class="h1-carousel edit1 mb-5 caption-top">OVER</h1>
            <h1 class="h1-carousel mb-5 caption-bottom">UNDER</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#CarouselTextAnim" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#CarouselTextAnim" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.6.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-KsvD1yqQ1/1+IA7gi3P0tyJcT3vR+NdBTt13hSJ2lnve8agRGXTTyNaBYmCR/Nwi" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-nsg8ua9HAw1y0W1btsyWgBklPnCUAFLuTMS2G72MMONqmOymq585AcH49TLBQObG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made many, many changes to your (second) code.

#### HTML

- All unnecessary imports (*animated.css*, *jquery*, *font-awesome*) have been removed.
- In the `h1` with classes `caption-top` and `caption-bottom` that don't correspond to the first slide, the class `hidden` has been added.

#### CSS

- `.carousel-caption` was replaced by `.carousel-top`, but another `.carousel-caption` was added to set default `top` property.
- `.slide` was replaced by `.hidden`, for better understanding.
- Previous values have been put as comments.

#### JS

Here is the fun! Changes and explanation:

- `slideclass` was replaced with `hiddenClass`.
- All selected `.caption-top` have been set to `topcap`, and all `.carousel-caption` to `captions`.
- The `currentItem` and `nextItem` variables have the functionality to store the current and next `.carousel-caption` element of each slide.
- On [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event), the first `.carousel-caption` element (zero position), corresponding to the first slide, has been set to `currentItem`.
- In both event types `slide.bs.carousel` and `slid.bs.carousel` the `relatedTarget` property is used.
  [Bootstrap's documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/#events) says:

> `relatedTarget`: The DOM element that is being slid into place as the active item.

[`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling) here refers to the element immediately following it. Looking at the html, we know that after a `.caption-item` there is a `.carousel-caption`. I think [`firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/firstElementChild) and [`lastElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/lastElementChild) need no explanation :)

- At `slid.bs.carousel`, `nextItem` is shown, and at `slide.bs.carousel`, `currentItem` is hidden (as it transitions to the next slide).

```js
const topcap = document.querySelectorAll(".caption-top");
const bottomcap = document.querySelectorAll(".caption-bottom");
const captions = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel-caption");
const hiddenClass = "hidden";

var TACarousel = document.querySelector("#CarouselTextAnim");

let currentItem, nextItem;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
  currentItem = captions[0];
});

TACarousel.addEventListener("slid.bs.carousel", function(e) {
  currentItem = e.relatedTarget.nextElementSibling;

  nextItem.firstElementChild.classList.remove(hiddenClass);
  nextItem.lastElementChild.classList.remove(hiddenClass);
});

TACarousel.addEventListener("slide.bs.carousel", function(e) {
  nextItem = e.relatedTarget.nextElementSibling;

  currentItem.firstElementChild.classList.add(hiddenClass);
  currentItem.lastElementChild.classList.add(hiddenClass);
});
```

```css
.carousel-inner .carousel-item {
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}

.h1-carousel {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(2, 15, 19, 0.7);
  font-family: "Julius Sans One";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 4vw;
  /*transition: 0.4s;*/
}

.carousel-caption {
  top: 40%;
}

.caption-top {
  position: relative; /*absolute*/
  top: 0; /*<= added*/
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .4s;
}

.caption-top.hidden {
  top: -90vh; /*0*/
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .4s;
}

.caption-bottom {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 4vh;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .4s;
}

.caption-bottom.hidden {
  bottom: -90vh;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .4s;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Top Motion Productions</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,300italic,400,700|Julius+Sans+One|Roboto+Condensed:300,400" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 0" id="carousel">
    <section class="slideshow">
      <div id="CarouselTextAnim" class="carousel slide carousel-slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="2000" data-bs-pause="false">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="https://cutewallpaper.org/21/black-1920x1080-wallpaper/Dark-Desktop-Backgrounds-1920x1080-,-Best-Background-Images-.jpg" class="img-carousel d-block w-100" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1 id="carousel1" class="h1-carousel mb-5 caption-top">TOP CAPTION</h1>
            <h1 class="h1-carousel mb-5 caption-bottom">BOTTOM CAPTION</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/THsknvO.jpg" class="img-carousel d-block w-100" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1 class="h1-carousel edit1 mb-5 caption-top hidden">UP TOP</h1>
            <h1 class="h1-carousel mb-5 caption-bottom hidden">DOWN LOW</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/z7tXPkz.jpg" class="img-carousel d-block w-100" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1 class="h1-carousel edit1 mb-5 caption-top hidden">OVER</h1>
            <h1 class="h1-carousel mb-5 caption-bottom hidden">UNDER</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#CarouselTextAnim" data-bs-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#CarouselTextAnim" data-bs-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-nsg8ua9HAw1y0W1btsyWgBklPnCUAFLuTMS2G72MMONqmOymq585AcH49TLBQObG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! I'd been tinkering with it on my own some more in the mean time, and found out some of the things you mention myself, but I was still stuck quite a way from a proper end result. I'm going to dive into your code until I understand exactly what each part does. :) My gratitude is endless!

Comment: I understand you perfectly, it wasn't easy for me either. The debugger and _trial and error_ are good friends in these cases :D

Comment: https://codepen.io/AlexanderSplat/pen/OJpBoeN if you're interested in how far I'd gotten on my own in the mean time.

Comment: Actually, if you don't mind another question: what change between your code and mine specifically (if there's something specific to point to) cuts the tie between the carousel-caption and the carousel-item? Why doesn't your caption move sideways along with the slide, and mine does? I can't figure that part out.

Comment: As compared to the snippet in your question or the pen in the comment above?

Comment: Oooh, no, wait, I'm sorry. I'm mixing up my own snippets. :) I was looking at the result of the first snippet in my question, which does go diagonally, and the code of my second, which doesn't. No, then it makes sense. It's because in the 'diagonal version' the caption `div` is within the item `div`, which originally I thought was the only way to make the captions do anything upon each slide change.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const topcap = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel-caption");
const bottomcap = document.querySelectorAll(".caption-bottom");
const slideclass = ("slide");

var TACarousel = document.querySelector("#CarouselTextAnim");

TACarousel.addEventListener("slide.bs.carousel", function() {
  topcap.forEach(cap => cap.classList.add(slideclass));
  bottomcap.forEach(cap => cap.classList.add(slideclass));
});

TACarousel.addEventListener("slid.bs.carousel", function() {
  topcap.forEach(cap => cap.classList.remove(slideclass));
  bottomcap.forEach(cap => cap.classList.remove(slideclass));
});
```

```css
.carousel-inner .carousel-item {
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}

.h1-carousel {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(2, 15, 19, 0.70);
  font-family: 'Julius Sans One';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 4vw;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s;
}

.carousel-caption.slide {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.caption-bottom {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 4vh;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s;
}

.caption-bottom.slide {
  bottom: -90vh;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Top Motion Productions</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.2/css/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.2/css/v4-shims.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,300italic,400,700|Julius+Sans+One|Roboto+Condensed:300,400" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 0" id="carousel">
    <section class="slideshow">
      <div id="CarouselTextAnim" class="carousel slide carousel-slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="2000" data-bs-pause="false">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="https://cutewallpaper.org/21/black-1920x1080-wallpaper/Dark-Desktop-Backgrounds-1920x1080-,-Best-Background-Images-.jpg" class="img-carousel d-block w-100" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1 id="carousel1" class="h1-carousel mb-5 caption-top">TOP CAPTION</h1>
              <h1 class="h1-carousel mb-5 caption-bottom">BOTTOM CAPTION</h1>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/THsknvO.jpg" class="img-carousel d-block w-100" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1 class="h1-carousel edit1 mb-5 caption-top">UP TOP</h1>
              <h1 class="h1-carousel mb-5 caption-bottom">DOWN LOW</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/z7tXPkz.jpg" class="img-carousel d-block w-100" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1 class="h1-carousel edit1 mb-5 caption-top">OVER</h1>
              <h1 class="h1-carousel mb-5 caption-bottom">UNDER</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#CarouselTextAnim" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#CarouselTextAnim" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.6.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-KsvD1yqQ1/1+IA7gi3P0tyJcT3vR+NdBTt13hSJ2lnve8agRGXTTyNaBYmCR/Nwi" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-nsg8ua9HAw1y0W1btsyWgBklPnCUAFLuTMS2G72MMONqmOymq585AcH49TLBQObG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.js"></script>
</body>
```

Just change the 2s to 1s transition speed.Please check the snippet

Comment: Thanks, but I only made the main transition two seconds and the captions 1 second to better show the effect. It should actually be 1 second for the main one and 0.4 for the captions. I don't want them to have the same transition time. That's why I need to separate them.

Comment: Also, your version still has the captions going diagonally. Do you know of a way to get them to go straight up?